# Polymorphism Trouble in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, function-calls

I'm trying to access a data member of a derived class through its base class and I'm having some trouble.

Here is the code:

```
for (auto actor : drawables) {
    if (actor.isDrawable()) {
        std::vector<glm::vec3> verts = actor.getVerticies();
        for (glm::vec3 v : verts) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to run this, it says that verts has a size of 0 when I know I have added vec3's into the vector.

I have a base class called Actor3D that has the following properties:

```
    class Actor3D
    {
    private:
    static int actorCount;

    protected:
    int id;
    bool _isDrawable;

    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;

    std::vector<glm::vec3> verts;
    //std::vector<glm::vec3> color;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;

    virtual void addVert(float x, float y, float z);

    public:
    virtual std::vector<glm::vec3> getVerticies() const { return verts; }
    ...
    }
```

And then I have a derived class with the following definition:

```
    #include "engine\Actor3D.h"

    class Cube : public Actor3D
    {
    public:
    Cube();
    ~Cube();
    };
```

In the cpp file:

```
    Cube::Cube()
    {
    _isDrawable = true;

    position.x = 5;
    position.y = 5;
    position.z = 7;

    addVert(-1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    addVert(-1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    addVert(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    addVert(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    }

    Cube::~Cube()
    {
    }
```

Is there some way I can access the verts vector through the base class in my for loop?

Comment: Can you post the implementations of `Cube::addVert` and `Cube::getVertices`?

Comment: Please don't use tab (`'\t'`) characters when posting _formatted_ code here!! Use a decent IDE or some text editor to reformat your tab characters to 4 (or less) spaces, befor inserting it in the markup form. I have edited your 1st code section to demonstrate what I mean, please do so for the other code sections.

Comment: Is there code that actually adds a vert to the verts in Actor3D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems correct, but you don't show you how are populating `drawables` and the body of `addVert`. If you could provide a small example that we could compile and run that would be better. It should not be hard for this use case.

Note that you don't need to define the methods as virtual, unless you modify their behavior in the derived class, but it should not be the case for these ones.

Also `getVerticies()` (should be `getVertices()`) returns a copy of your vector, it may not be intended.

When you write `for (auto actor : drawables)` you are copying actor and all its content, it is probably not what you meant, I would write `for (auto const &actor : drawables)`

Do you also know about slicing? If your `drawables` is declared as `std::vector<Actor3d>` it contains only the Base class and not the derived! 
Right now your code should work if you create a cube and add it to `drawables`, because your example does not use anything specific to `Cube`.

Again if you provide a small reproducible case it will be easier. With a link to http://ideone.com/sphere-engine it would be perfect :)